# Any benchmarks for Cassandra Trigger performance?

Tags: cassandra, apache-storm

Would appreciate if anyone could share some practical experience on the impact of using the prototype Trigger support in Cassandra 2.0 . In particular as to how it affects write performance.

Use case is to bind the trigger to a Storm spout when data in a Cassandra CF is updated.